# CakePhp Ajax Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, cakephp-2.1, json

I am trying to get Ajax autocomplete setup for a textbox in CakePhp 2.x.

In my view I have:

```
<?php $this->start('script'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options, a;
        jQuery(function() {
            options = { 
                serviceUrl: "<?php echo $this->Html->Url(array('Controller' => 'Logs', 'action' => 'autoComplete')); ?>",
                minChars: 2,
            };
            a = $('#LogTimeSpent').autocomplete(options);
        });
    });
    $('#saveCust').click(function () {
        alert("Test")
    });
</script>
<?php $this->end(); ?>
```

In my controller I have:

```
function autoComplete($query) {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
    {
        $suggestions = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Customer.fullName LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%'
                )
            ));
        return json_encode(array('query' => $query, 'suggestions' => $suggestions));

    }
}
```

Customer.fullName is a virtual field if that affects the query.  Firebug is currently giving me a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out you have to do something special for virtual fields to work.  I decided that a virtual field isn't the way to go so I got that updated.  The $`query` as a parameter is also incorrect, and that I needed to get the querystring from `$this->params['url']['query'];` instead.  Finally, rather than returning `json_encode` I needed to use `_serialize`.  Here is my updated Controller, so hopefully this will help somebody out.  My view is correct in the original post.

```
function autoComplete() {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax'))
    {
        $query = $this->params['url']['query'];
        $this->set('query', $query);

        $customer = $this->Log->Customer->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'OR' => array(
                    'Customer.first_name LIKE' => '%'.$query.'%',
                    'Customer.last_name LIKE' => '%'.$query .'%'
                )),
            'fields' => array(
                'Customer.first_name', 'Customer.last_name'
                )
            ));

        $names = array();
        $id = array();
        foreach ($customer as $cust) {
            $fullName = $cust['Customer']['last_name'] . ', ' . $cust['Customer']['first_name'];
            array_push($names, $fullName);
            array_push($id, $cust['Customer']['id']);
        }
        $this->set('suggestions', $names);
        $this->set('data', $id);
        $this->set('_serialize', array('query', 'suggestions', 'data'));        
    }
}
```